# how to source a csh script in bash to set the environment

Tags: bash, csh

We have Oracle running on Solaris, and the shell is by default csh. So the login script sets the oracle_home, oracle_sid in csh also. But I don't like csh and want to use bash to do my work. So how to source the csh login script in bash?

e.g, the following is what in the .cshrc file. And when use bash, I'd like use these variables. One way is to copy the variables again and use bash command, such as export ORACLE_SID=TEST. But doing so will require us to maintain two copies of the files. And when we change the database name, or upgrade the database, I need to maintain the bash login file separately. It's nice to just use something like

source .cshr in bash, but it doesn't work.

```
setenv ORACLE_SID TEST
setenv ORACLE_HOME /oracle/TEST/home/products/10204
setenv EPC_DISABLED TRUE
setenv MANPATH /usr/local/man:/usr/share/man
setenv EDITOR vi
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $ORACLE_HOME/lib:/usr/sfw/lib/64
setenv NLS_LANG AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
setenv NLS_DATE_FORMAT "DD-MON-RR"
```

Comment: More appropriate for Super User or Server Fault?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc` (or the first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` that exists) source this script using something like `. ~/bin/sourcecsh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This should be sourced rather than executed
while read cmd var val
do
    if [[ $cmd == "setenv" ]]
    then
        eval "export $var=$val"
    fi
done < ~/.cshrc
```

This version eliminates the evil `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This should be sourced rather than executed
# yes, it will be sourcing within sourcing - what so(u)rcery!
source /dev/stdin < \
<(
    while read cmd var val
    do
        if [[ $cmd == "setenv" ]]
        then
             echo "export $var=$val"
        fi
    done < cshrc
)
```

**Edit:**

Without sourcing stdin:

```
while read cmd var val
do
    if [[ $cmd == "setenv" ]]
    then
        declare -x "$var=$val"
    fi
done < cshrc
```

Comment: @Dennis - nice... I like this one since it's pure bash (mine uses `sed`)... I must admit that I still prefer my version (fairly similar) mostly since it keeps the list of set commands as a file for later troubleshooting or environment restoration just in case :)

Comment: I'll vote for the first version -- sourcing stdin is at least as trouble-prone as `eval`.

Answer (score 7):

How about just defining a function called setenv, like so

```
setenv() {
  echo setting $1 to $2
  export $1=$2
}
```

and then sourcing the .cshrc file.

When I do this in bash, I get

```
[dws@oxygen ual-read-only]$ source cshrc
setting ORACLE_SID to TEST
setting ORACLE_HOME to /oracle/TEST/home/products/10204
setting EPC_DISABLED to TRUE
setting MANPATH to /usr/local/man:/usr/share/man
setting EDITOR to vi
setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /oracle/TEST/home/products/10204/lib:/usr/sfw/lib/64
setting NLS_LANG to AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT to DD-MON-RR
[dws@oxygen ual-read-only]$ env | grep ORACLE
ORACLE_SID=TEST
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/TEST/home/products/10204
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. (1) some of the csh source scripts set aliases - and I don't know how to export aliases from csh back to a calling shell like bash.  I suppose it's just a simple matter of programming to translate any csh alias to a bash alias, and vice versa (the latter for calling new csh source scripts). (2) since my normal login shell has extra encvironmenht variables, I need to empty it first.  And this is what I am asking.  (3), oh, just noticed exactly what you are doing: yes, I have had a setenv in bash for many years now. (Actually, since before bash existed, in ksh.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the same boat.  A coworker showed me the following:

Start off in bash, without the stuff in thwe environment:

```
bash> echo $$
12632
bash> echo $FOO
```

Here's the csh file that gets source'd:

```
bash> cat setup-env.csh
setenv FOO "some csh stuff"
echo FOO=$FOO in csh
```

Here's the command:

```
bash> csh -c 'source setup-env.csh;exec bash'
```

Look at the output from csh

```
FOO=some csh stuff in csh
```

And look at the output from the new bash shell

```
  bash> echo $$
  13487
  bash> echo $FOO
  some csh stuff
```

Now leave, and go back to the original bash shell

```
bash> exit
exit
bash> echo $$
12632
bash>
```

Note the echo $$ to see the process IDs, so that we can see they are different shell processes.

My coworker uses this enough that he puts it into an alias, like:

```
# make csh environment scripts useable (sourceable) from bash function 
# from Phil McCoy, Wed Nov  9 2011
source_csh () {
   exec csh -c " source $*; setenv ALREADY_SOURCED \"$ALREADY_SOURCED:$*:\"; exec bash"
}
# sounds like a great idea to do source_csh .cshrc or .login
# but naively done is infinitely recursive, 
# since the exec'ed bash will run .bashrc
```

Unfortunately, I have found that I often needed not just environment variable setup, but also aliases setup, as in the modules package http://modules.sourceforge.net/.

I have been able to automate this "csh source script recipes" by using Perl Expect.  But I have not been able to be as interactive as I would like, except for the above.

Comment: I am a big fan of the modules package and I am surprised more people do not use it. Making things shell agnostic is just a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can think to do it would be to load csh and then call bash from that new shell. That way csh could parse that file, and then the bash that it spawns would inherit that environment as well.

Comment: In code: `(cat .cshrc; echo exec $SHELL) | csh`

Answer (score 2):

In your bash `.profile`, you can do the following:

```
cat .cshrc | sed 's/setenv\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$/set $1=$2; export $1/' > $HOME/.env_from_csh
source $HOME/.env_from_csh
```

Comment: It's also cool, I prefer not create some junk file. Not sure whether we can just use pipe to avoid the temporary file.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Bash doesn't use `set` that way. `export` can take the variable name and assignment all at once. You must be using a different version of `sed` because that looks like Perl syntax. You need to use `-r` or escape the parentheses and plus signs. You can eliminate the temporary file like this: `source /dev/stdin < <(sed 's/setenv\s\+\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)$/export \1=\2/' .cshrc)`

Comment: @Dennis and Daniel - I usually **want** that "junk" temporary file :)

Comment: `source /dev/stdin < <(sed 's/setenv\s\+\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)$/export \1=\2/' .cshrc | tee $HOME/.env_from_csh)`

Answer (score 0):

For something that small, it's common to maintain two setup scripts, one for sh and sh-derived, shells, and one for csh and tcsh.  As you mention, that does create the risk of the two scripts getting out of sync -- *unless* you generate one from the other, or generate both from a common source.

This places the burden on the maintainer of the setup script(s) rather than on each user who needs to use them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module available by which you can source same file where ever you want in perl script. And you will get all environment paths available in your csh file.

```
Source::Shell
```

Go through a little documentation for its usage.

Answer (score -2):

Just having a "`#!/bin/tcsh`" or similar statement available at the start of the CSH script in conjunction with making the script executable solved the problem for me. I could directly call the CSH script from bash in this case.

As an example, I had to run tools.csh from a bash script called setup.sh. I did something like this in the bash script:

```
if [ -z \`head -1 tools.csh | grep '^#!'\` ];
then
   TCSH=\`which tcsh\`;
   echo "'#!'$TCSH" > tools.csh.temp;
   cat tools.csh >> tools.csh.temp;
   mv tools.csh.temp tools.csh;
fi;
chmod 755 tools.csh;
./tools.csh
# now I have all the setenv commands effective ...
```

Comment: If `./tools.csh` sets environment variables, they *won't* be visible from the calling shell.  If the commands that depends on those environment variables are all in `./tools.csh`, that's ok.

Answer (score -4):

Sourcing a csh file in bash will not work. You can change the default login shell from csh to bash if you are more confortable in bash. You could use chsh or as an admin to change it for you.

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```