# Have common alias file between bash, csh and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, csh, tcsh

I use zsh on my personal laptop and bash/tcsh at work and tcsh in school. I've setup git in all locations making it easy to keep them in sync.

I want to know if it's possible to use a common file for aliases for all 3 shells and invoke a script from the respective rc files to convert it to the shell-specific syntax. How would I go about doing it? This may not be a good approach; I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: If your aliases are trivial, the question is trivial, too.  If your aliases are less trivial, it's easy to say "impossible", and hard to say anything constructive without a sample of what your alises look like.  Anyhow, to preserve your sanity, try to migrate off csh/tcsh.

Comment: Sounds like a maintenance nightmare. Also, I agree with triplee. See [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710848/26428) interesting.

Comment: I completely agree with all the opinions about Csh; that is why I use zsh on my comp. However, Csh is used in school and it is not in my power to change that. :(

Comment: What power is stopping you from typing `exec /bin/sh -l` (or zsh, or ksh or bash) in the C shell? You can even put that in `.cshrc` if you can't modify your login shell. Or is it that assignments must be handed in using the C shell (ugh)?

Comment: @jens has a very good point. Nothing stops you from starting up the shell of your choice once you've logged in,barring unavailability, and that too can be remedied by keeping a local copy in `~/bin`.

Comment: I understand and agree that simply sticking to a Bourne-heritage shell is the simplest solution. However, we need to run certain scripts to be able to use tools like Virtuoso or Modelsim etc. These scripts are written for tcsh

Answer (score -4):

As you already suggested, it *is* the wrong approach. The right approach is to simply use a Bourne-heritage shell on all your systems, whether that's zsh, ksh, bash, plain sh or even busybox. This way all your aliases are in Bourne syntax and your only worry is whether aliases are supported at all (archaic sh does not) and if they apply to your shell (zsh has global aliases with `alias -g` which other shells have not).

At school you should be able to invoke a Bourne-heritage shell, with, e.g.

```
 exec /bin/sh -l
```

either at the prompt or in your `.cshrc`. Maybe your administrator even allows you to select the shell of your dreams.

Comment: Check out chsh, which is normally provided to let users pick their login shell without needing root.