# Use C shell alias variables except for one

Tags: unix, alias, csh

I would like to make an alias that uses the first cli variable as an input to something and puts the rest of the variables in the end, like for example:

```
alias rerun '`head -n 2 \!:1/some_log_file.log | tail -n 1` \!:*'
```

In the example, I would like to use the first variable as the directory name and all the other variables (except for the first) at the end,

EDIT:
what I am currently getting from the example above is: first argument goes to the directory name as planned, and all of the arguments altogether go to the end like this (test is the directory containing the log file):

```
% rerun test foo bar foo
<executed_cmd> test foo bar foo
```

I want:

```
<executed_cmd> foo bar foo
```

so that I can pass extra arguments to the executed command (unlimited)

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Consider editing your question to include information about what happens when you use this code. It looks like it might work. GOod luck.

Comment: Bash and sh enable you to write subroutines, making what you want to do trivial.  All the cool kids use bash, you should too.

Comment: Yeah I know, at home and at my university I use Bash, but at work they use CSH so I don't really have a choice

Answer (score 0):

you want to use several parameters in an alias, you can do this:

- define a function in `~/.bashrc` ([or the one related to `csh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710848/1983854))
- define the alias in the same file

For example:

```
myalias_func()
{
        ls -ltr $1 >> /tmp/$2
}
alias myalias=myalias_func
```

In your case,

```
rerun_func()
{
head -n 2 ...
}
alias rerun=rerun_func
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Note the link you include is only converting csh `setenv var = value` to bash fmt `var=value`. We all know bash is better than csh, but some people have no choice in the shell they can use, and others, choose to use it. Good luck to all.