# source shell script on different shell (csh and bash)

Tags: shell

I need to write a single script that set a variable using setenv or export depending on the shell (bash, csh)

ex

```
my_shell=`ps -p $$ | grep $$ | awk '{print $4}'`
if [ "$my_shell" = "bash" ]
then
    export x=1
else
    setenv x 1
fi
```

I know that the csh and bash have different syntax for the of statement, but is there a way to workaround this

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to source a csh script in bash to set the enviroment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710790/how-to-source-a-csh-script-in-bash-to-set-the-enviroment)

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is a trick which might help.

First you write the script in either shell's syntax. I'm using csh here:

```
 setenv x 1
```

now you can do this:

```
csh -c 'source setup-env.csh;exec bash'
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982367/34088))

This will create a C shell with the correct environment. Starting a BASH inside of this shell will export all the environment variables to it.

Alternatively, you can create a function `setenv` in BASH:

```
setenv() {
  echo setting $1 to $2
  export $1=$2
}
```

This will only work for simple csh scripts, of course.