# I need to load some modules but load module doesn't work in my environment unless I change the bash profile. How do I do this in tcsh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, module, tcsh

. ~/.bashrc  is what I'm use to source the bash script in bash shell. But I have quite a few scripts that I want to run from tcsh.But this command  doesn't work for tcsh. Why doesn't this work? Is there a different file similar to bash profile when I work on t shell?

Any links to look up?

Thx!

Comment: bash and tcsh are entirely different shells. You will not be able to `source ~/.bashrc` from tcsh. You can run a shell script of any type as long as that shell script has the appropriate `shebang` in its first line, but it'll run on its own and not in the context of your interactive tcsh instance. Why don't you show us what you're actually trying to do, along with any errors you're getting, and we can help you come up with a solution?

Comment: @ghoti; good point, thought, OP wanted a `tcsh` equivalent of `.bashrc`

Comment: I'm trying to run a configuration script, that only runs without throwing syntax errors if I run from tcsh. (I don't have admin rights btw)  I can load modules by changing the bash script and commands are available while I'm in bash. As soon as I change to tcsh I don't have any commands on the shell since I don't know anything that is equivalent to sourcing the bash script , in tcsh.

Answer (score 1):

The `tcsh` equivalent to the `bash` and posix shell `.` is `source`.

That said, `bash` and `tcsh` are entirely different shells. You will not be able to `source ~/.bashrc` from tcsh, if that was your intent.

You can run a shell script of any type as long as that shell script has the appropriate `shebang` in its first line, but it'll run in its own process, and not in the context of your interactive tcsh instance.

If, for example, you have a directory: `~/.tcshrc.d`, and you want to include all the files in that directory in your login shell, you might include the following in your `.tcshrc` file:

```
foreach i ( ~/.tcshrc.d/* )
        source $i
end
```

Note that this is `tcsh` code, and is not compatible with `bash`.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't something like this work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710848/499581

Comment: @l'L'l, I think the question you linked to goes in the opposite direction to what the OP is asking for -- it provides bash code that would read a csh/tcsh script. That said, more clarification in the question would be helpful.